# Why libudev version ubuntu3.1 doesn't exist?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, systemd, versions

Recently (about a week ago) I installed Kubuntu 22.04 to my both machines (laptop and pc).

Everything went fine till I  noticed that I need to compile software and I cannot find `libudev-dev` package, it says that version mismatches ( `libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 249.11-0ubuntu3) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed` ).

I checked on my laptop, previously it showed (maybe old database) that package `libudev-dev_249ubuntu3.1` existed, but when I tried to install, it...suddenly said its doesn't exist at all.

I checked several repos, somewhere I could find 3.1, but on the next morning it has been removed everywhere!

In fact, I cannot downgrade to 3, I cannot upgrade on 3.3 (it breaks half of my system!), I cannot compile software since I do not have dev files for 3.1, and any new installations (I've tested on VM) comes again with `ubuntu3` version with not even mentioning 3.1.

Where did it come from and why is it existed in the first place?!

```
libudev1:
  Installed: 249.11-0ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
     249.11-0ubuntu3.3 1 (phased 0%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 249.11-0ubuntu3.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libudev-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     249.11-0ubuntu3.3 1 (phased 0%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Now I have to reinstall my both machines to bring back version 3!
[image: VM Clear install and installation of week ago, versions!]

Comment: @Nmath Now it is readable.

Comment: i'm sorry, english is not my main language, i had to compile wine, and it's demand libudev-dev. I used command "apt install libudev-dev" and it's said "Depends: libudev1 (= 249.11-0ubuntu3) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed", meanings, that version of libudev i currently have - has no longer dev package for and no longer exist in repository at all.

Comment: Why would you "compile wine", but not just install it by `sudo apt install wine`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `apt policy libudev1 && apt policy libudev-dev` command.

Comment: I tried, but, version that comes with distro refused to run my working apps, while 6.10 and 7.0 running it well. I did exactly the same actions (dll overrides and winetricks components) but it's just refuses to run :( while on my previous build (20.04, wine 6.10) it worked flawless

Comment: This seems like a possible variation of bug LP:[#1979244](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1979244), *Users cannot install a package, e.g. libssl-dev, if built from the same source as another installed update while it is phasing.* `apt policy` output indicates that both packages involved do seem to be phasing.

Comment: i added output of apt policy

Comment: I had the same problem, solved doing this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417403/can-not-install-libudev-dev-on-ubuntu-22-04/1417416#1417416

Answer (score 0):

The initial install comes with `libudev1` version `249.11-0ubuntu3`.

After you get updates of your system, you receive `249.11-0ubuntu3.3`.

Probably before there was an update to `249.11-0ubuntu3.1`.

So everything looks correct.

Keep your system updated and all dependencies should be OK. Trying to "downgrade", etc. will break your system completely.

Maybe you forget to run `sudo apt update` before you try to install something. This will update package lists.

After that

```
sudo apt install libudev-dev
```

should work.

In your current state the updates are phased. You need to wait a bit, when they settle down. It is a bug in the updates system.

Comment: was it minor update that no longer comes with system? but, again, any fresh installs with full upgrading still has 3 :( and im kind hanged up between 2 solutions, wait for 3.3 or reinstall entire system to be able done my work, and i actually have not so much time to wait...seems like reinstall is an option

Comment: If you do a full upgrade, you should have the `3.3`, unless you are using some mirror that is behind. Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: i use original repo (archive.ubuntu.com) and section of "upgrades" are not available for me (system says that all is up to date), so, again, stuck. that was such a strange decision from them to even make 3.1 if they got rid of it this fast...

Comment: You can clearly see in the repos that the current version is `3.3` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libudev1

Comment: Is `jammy-updates` repo enabled in your system?

Comment: yes, of course it is. i cant understand why i cant use these updates ..maybe KDE not compatible with it yet? because when i try to force 3.3, it tries to remove my KDE environment

Comment: Don't force anything. `libudev-dev` is also `249.11-0ubuntu3.3`

Comment: for information purposes: 249.11-0ubuntu3.1 was uploaded in Jammy on April 25.  Later on, it was superseded by 249.11-0ubuntu3.2 and -0ubuntu3.3 in the same upload, on June 7.  If anyonie had an install and NOT updated since June 22nd, they'd have have the -0ubuntu3.1 version which shipped with non-updated Jammy.  (I thought the timeline would be helpful here, extracted from the package history on Launchpad for systemd)