# Can not install "libudev-dev" on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, dependencies, compiling, 22.04, ffmpeg

I am trying to compile FFMPEG from source because I need to manually build it with AMD AMF drivers to get GPU hardware acceleration.

Following Ubuntu FFMPEG build instructions:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

When I run this command as needed for dependencies before building FFMPEG:

```
sudo apt-get update -qq && sudo apt-get -y install \
  autoconf \
  automake \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  git-core \
  libass-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libgnutls28-dev \
  libmp3lame-dev \
  libsdl2-dev \
  libtool \
  libva-dev \
  libvdpau-dev \
  libvorbis-dev \
  libxcb1-dev \
  libxcb-shm0-dev \
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
  meson \
  ninja-build \
  pkg-config \
  texinfo \
  wget \
  yasm \
  zlib1g-dev
```

I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 249.11-0ubuntu3) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Seems like Ubuntu wants to install a newer version of libudev1 which libudev-dev does not accept.

How to fix this issue?

Using Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by doing the following:

Go to the "Software & Updates" on Ubuntu.

Then on "Ubuntu Software" tab, make sure all of the check boxes at "Downloadable from the Internet" section are checked.

Same goes for the "Other Software" tab.

Same goes for the "Developer Options" tab where the check box section for:
"Pre-released updates" is also checked.

Then on terminal I enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now I do not get that error anymore when running the dependency command.

Comment: Didn't work for me, unfortunately. Fully updated 22.04 as of the time of writing. `aptitude` was not installed, I installed it, and `aptitude full-upgrade` did nothing.